# Redirect with a QUERYSTRING help - migrating site

Tags: pcp, urls

I'm moving our civi from Joomla to Wordpress and as a part of the process I wanted to set up some redirects for our existing PCP pages. As you all know civi URLs are kind of long: baseurl.com/sub_dir/index.php/component/civicrm/?task=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=XX

I've found several posts explaining query string redirects like this one (http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/) but in all of them their variable is right after the "?". I have tried the following to no avail:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} task=civicrm/pcp/info&reset=1&id=20$
RewriteRule ^sub_dir/index\.php/component/civicrm/$ /path-to-new-location/? [L,R=301]
```

Eventually, I do want to write it with variables (as we have several hundred PCPs but I wanted to get something working first.) Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apache, not CiviCRM.  I think you'll get better answers on webmasters.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I've scoured those sites a bit and have struggled to find an appropriate solution, I just thought someone in the civi world would have done something similar before. Wasn't trying to break the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my above code was correct, save for I was putting it in our main directory's htaccess file. Once placed in the subdirectory's file (and "sub_dir" removed) all is right!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Joomla person, but Drupal has a "URL Aliases" module that lets you do redirects from within Drupal.  It looks like [Joomla has something similar](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/303-using-the-redirect-manager).

Comment: So it does, never knew that existed. Unfortunately, I most likely won't be able to keep the old install up when the new Wordpress site is live. But I did test it and it does not seem to be playing nice - perhaps that means I have a bigger issue. I will continue to read on the redirect manager in the case it does present a viable solution, thank you.